# Looking for duplicate values between 2 tables sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables, and the 2 tables has the concatenate value of 2 columns.
For example,

```
column1| column2| concatenate value
   A         B             AB
```

Now, when I count the the 2 table, the value on the 2nd table(newly created table) appear to have more value than original table. What can I do to find out which value is the extra?

I had tried, but the code does not work:

```
SELECT concat (fullVisitorId, cast(visitId as string)) as fullvisitor_visitId_tableA 
FROM  `ga_sessions_*` 
where _table_suffix between '20220101' and '20220130'
UNION all
SELECT concat (fullVisitorId, cast(visitId as string)) as fullvisitor_visitId_tableB 
FROM  `test_ps_ga360_total_3`
EXCEPT 
SELECT concat (fullVisitorId, cast(visitId as string)) as fullvisitor_visitId_tableA 
FROM  `ga_sessions_*` 
where _table_suffix between '20220101' and '20220130'
INTERSECT
SELECT concat (fullVisitorId, cast(visitId as string)) as fullvisitor_visitId_tableB 
FROM `test_ps_ga360_total_3`;
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you just looking for rows in tableB that aren't in TableA (be they duplicates or completely different)? Or also rows in TableA that aren't in TableB?

Comment: Does it matter that the CONCAT of `x` and `xy` is the same as the CONCAT of `xx` and `y`? (Why are you comparing the concatenation, rather than the source columns?)

Comment: Could you please add more details to your question ? Add please some example lines of table 1 and table 2, the query you are running and the output that is wrong, also the output you would like to achieve. This behavior is probably because of the nature of the data it self, add the data sample please.

Comment: Hello guys, I have found an answer. I will post it later on this post when I am free. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to solve a problem similar to this once. I would add another column to Table 1 (columns 1 & 2) that is your concatenated column (Column 3) and then do a left join on that to the other table that you are looking for the missing values from.

Step 1:

```
ALTER TABLE `ga_sessions_*` 
ADD column_3 varchar(250);
```

Step 2:

```
UPDATE `ga_sessions_*` SET column_3 = CONCAT(column_1,column_2);
```

Step 3:

Then do a *LEFT JOIN on column_3 & concatenate value (AB)
WHERE column_3 is null*

Should give you the output of all the extra values in AB

Comment: Hello guys, I have found an answer. I will post it later on this post when I am free. I will try this later and get back to you if it works. Much thanks.